# What can/should I do to save the contents of my "contenteditable" table in PHP?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

So, to start things up I'm a "newbie" at PHP so please don't discourage me.
Currently, I have created a form-type HTML that consists of radio button text area/fields and some "contenteditable" table to let users input data such as monitoring progress and acts like a spreadsheet.

I have successfully inserted and saved the rest of the data in my forms aside from the table input-types which I've been googling my issue for a week now but doesn't really help me since I cannot find an article related to it. Any tips guys? I don't wanna resort to changing it into a text-field type just to make it work.

myTable code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Implementation/Migration Plan</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-condensed" width="50">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Activities</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Responsible</th>
                        <th>Back-out Procedure</th>
                        <th>Remarks</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </table>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any tips on how can I save the data being input in the table?

Table sample:

[image: TABLE PICTURE SAMPLE]

Comment: You can fetch the data and post it with JavaScript without the need for an HTML form.

Comment: It has need to be in a HTML form.

Comment: _Content Editable does not work as a form element. Only javascript can allow it to work._ so you have to choose one - javascript or textarea.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here I think:

1 - if you are set on using `contenteditable` you will need to fetch and submit your data with Javascript.

2 - change your HTML to use a form instead.

The resulting PHP won't change as you can submit the data in the same manner through either method.

Personally I would recommend that you think carefully about why you wish to use `contenteditable` though as you end up having to work around the fact that it's not a form in order to get your data submitted.

Comment: use form meaning to convert/change it to textfield areas? sorry, im a bit stupid at programming.

Comment: @Kev - yes, either `textarea` or `input` tags and then make sure the entire thing is wrapped into a `form` tag